# Cordova - SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO npm http GET https

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, proxy, npm

I run the command **cordova platform add android** and I get the following error:

```
C:\Mobile>cordova platform add android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Mobile\hooks\before_platform_add\init_directories.js C:\Mobile
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.7.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.7.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.7.1
Unable to fetch platform android: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=8960:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:787:
```

I'm behind an enterprise proxy, it is already configured (proxy, https-proxy variables).
The configuration below is my **npm get** setting:

```
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
strict-ssl = false
```

I'm running on:

```
nodejs v.0.10.29
cordova v.4.3.0
npm v.1.4.14
```

How can I sort this out?

Comment: Same problem here!!, any ideas? I'm also behind a Enterprise Proxy